# How to return Content-Length header for TWIG rendered page?

Tags: php, http-headers, twig, content-length

I am rendering a TWIG template to generate a CSV file to download.  In order to show a progress bar for the download, the server must return the Content-Length header.

I tried rendering the TWIG template into a variable, calculating the length of this string, then outputting the content-length header immediately before echo'ing the rendered template:

```
$output = $twig->render(...);
header('Content-Length', strlen($output));
echo $output;
```

But this throws a server 500 error with the message "malformed header from script 'index.php': Bad header: Content-Length".

Am I missing something here? Seems this should be trivial.

Comment: Try `header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($output));`

Comment: @Nima What do you know... it worked!!! :)  Thanks for refraining from telling me how dumb I am.  I'm sure it was hard to bite your tongue at such a blatant error.  :)

Comment: No worries :) but I'm sure you just _assumed_ how header function works and did not read the docs ;)

Comment: Right you are.  I've used 'header()' many times but it's been a few weeks and a few thousand other functions' documentation that I've read since then. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter passed to `header()` should be the complete header string. I guess you expected header function to accept the first and second parameters like `header(field name,field value)`, but that's not the case. You should headers as a single string like this:

```
// something like 'Content length: 1234'
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($output));
```